# Convert VCard to CNContact

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, contacts

I am trying to convert a VCard 4.0 packet into a CN Contact and I get:

```
CNContactVCardSerialization.contactsWithData(localData)
2016-07-06 15:52:36.096 Setec[570:83203] bplist0
2016-07-06 15:52:36.097 Setec[570:83203] vCard Syntax Error, character: 7 : 0
2016-07-06 15:52:36.097 Setec[570:83203] Malformed BEGIN
2016-07-06 15:52:36.097 Setec[570:83203] (null)
2016-07-06 15:52:36.097 Setec[570:83203] vCard Syntax Error, character: 14 :
```

Here is my code:

```
 var usersContact = []
                            do {
                                try usersContact = CNContactVCardSerialization.contactsWithData(localData)
                                contactArray.addObject(usersContact)

                            } catch {
                                print("Error \(error)")
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the below and if you have any further issues feel free to let me know. Hope this helps **:)**

```
var usersContact = []
do {
    try usersContact = CNContactVCardSerialization.contactsWithData(data)
} catch {
    print("error")
}
var contact = usersContact[0] as! CNContact
```

Comment: Could this have anyything to do with me running vcard 4.0? There isn't much documentation but I have seen some hints that it isn't supported. 2016-07-07 07:37:50.964 Setec[248:7738] bplist0
2016-07-07 07:37:50.965 Setec[248:7738] vCard Syntax Error, character: 7 : 0
2016-07-07 07:37:50.965 Setec[248:7738] Malformed BEGIN
2016-07-07 07:37:50.965 Setec[248:7738] (null)
2016-07-07 07:37:50.965 Setec[248:7738] vCard Syntax Error, character: 14

Comment: Yeah it's possible that vcardserialization doesn't support that version yet

Comment: That is what I thought. Unfortunately Apple doesn't have documentation on it so I am shooting blind.